# css alignment with previous sibling

Tags: css, alignment

Considering the following :
http://jsfiddle.net/Johnny5/EC8kK/

I would like the input button to align right with the inner div, without wrapping with another element. Example :

```
|---div.container-------------------|
|                                   |
| |--div.box---------------|        |
| |                        |        |
| |------------------------|        |
|                                   |
|                |--input--|        |
|                |---------|        |
|                                   |
|-----------------------------------|
```

The width of `.box` is known, but not the width of the input. So I can't calculate exactly the `margin-left` for that input. I don't want to add a container `<div>` around .box and input. Don't really care for IE <= 7.

The ideal solution will modify *only* the css, without adding html markups.

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EC8kK/4/ and http://jsfiddle.net/EC8kK/5/ if you want the `input` to stay inside the `.container`

Comment: The input must be _outside_ the div.box.

Comment: I updated the fiddle, I had forgot to save changes before posting my question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/RcNSN/

And here is a code without modifying HTML. adjust the right margin, once you remove the borders.

http://jsfiddle.net/RcNSN/2/

Comment: Nice, but I would preffer a solution that does not modifiy original html, only css.

Comment: It's looking like you're going to have to since you don't know the width of the input.

Comment: Doesn't matter the input width. It simply must not exceed 100px, otherwise... ;-)

Comment: Yup, I got the exact same answer.

Comment: Your second fiddle (like Andrew's one) looks nice. But I my real world case the container's width is not fixed. But maybe I could force it to be.

In fact I was looking for a css property that would be directly related to the previous sibling position, maybe (probably) it does not exists at all.

Comment: This is CSS, not javascript :) You can't get the position of previous sibling. Don't spend your time on that. Add a new div to HTML, or use margin-right.

Comment: Well I Dream of A world where css would allow me to do such a thing :) But you're right, the solution with margin-right is the one. Lucky you, you posted it 2 minutes before Andrew. So thanks to both of you!

Comment: This solution would not work when the viewport gets resized.

Answer (score 3):

What about something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bGE2J/? It should work as long as your container isn't fluid.

Comment: @Johnny5 Fluid in pixels or %?

Comment: In my real website the container is in fact a `<td>`. The table has a fixed pixel width, but the number and content of cells depend on many parameters, so the size of this container TD depends of the contents of other's. Maybe I may fix the size fot this one.

Comment: I think that would be your best bet. Without doing to you couldn't position it properly 100% of the time.